# Python Pandas: Groupby Cumulative Sum, but avoiding sum where flag is 0

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

There's some questions about this topic already (like Pandas: Cumulative sum of one column based on value of another) however, none of them full fill my requirements.
Let's say I have a dataframe like this one:

```
id  flag
a   1
a   1
a   0
a   0
a   1
b   0
b   0
b   1
b   1
b   1
b   1
c   0
c   1
c   1
c   0
c   1
```

I want to compute the cumulative sum of flag grouping by id, but avoiding sum where flag is 0 and also cumsum reset to 0 again. I tried summing it up using `shift()`, `groupby(id)['flag']cumsum()` within `np.where` but no luck. Desired Output should be:

```
id  flag    cum_flag
a   1   1
a   1   2
a   0   0
a   0   0
a   1   1
b   0   0
b   0   0
b   1   1
b   1   2
b   1   3
b   1   4
c   0   0
c   1   1
c   1   2
c   0   0
c   1   1
```

The DDL to generate the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [a, a, a, a, a, b, b, b, b, b, b, c, c, c, c, c],
                 'flag': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]})
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cumsum()` to identify the consecutive blocks of `1`, and then `groupby`:

```
df['cum_flag'] = df.groupby(['id',(df['flag']==0).cumsum()]).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   id  flag  cum_flag
0   a     1         1
1   a     1         2
2   a     0         0
3   a     0         0
4   a     1         1
5   b     0         0
6   b     0         0
7   b     1         1
8   b     1         2
9   b     1         3
10  b     1         4
11  c     0         0
12  c     1         1
13  c     1         2
14  c     0         0
15  c     1         1
```